# Unable to resolve dependency when running dotnet core app from console

Tags: c#, postgresql, angular, .net-core

I am writing a client-server application using Dotnet Core web-api as the backend and Angular2 for the frontend. The persistence layer uses EntityFramework Core to access a postgre database. To try my application I added a database seeding class to create some test data to work with. With this class my problem started.

When I run the application from Visual Studio Code everything is working fine. If I start the application from the terminal with "dotnet run" I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Could not resolve a service of type 'OpenGameListApp.Data.DbSeeder' for the parameter 'dbSeeder' of method 'Configure' on type 'OpenGameListApp.Startup'. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseNpgsql(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 NpgsqlOptionsAction)
   at OpenGameListApp.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in /home/noam/projects/dotnet/OpenGameListApp/src/Startup.cs:line 43
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.DbContextOptionsFactory[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at OpenGameListApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/noam/projects/dotnet/OpenGameListApp/src/Program.cs:line 15
```

The code of the Startup.cs class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services
    services.AddMvc();

    // Add entity framework
    services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));    

    // Add database seeder
    services.AddSingleton<DbSeeder>();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DbSeeder dbSeeder)
{
    // Add logger
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    // Rewrite all routing urls including the root one to the index.html file by adding the following rules
    var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite(env.ContentRootFileProvider, "rewrite-rules.xml");

    // Add iis url rewrite features to kestrel            
    // Note: the app.UseRewriter method must be called before app.UseDefaultFiles and app.UseStaticFiles
    app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);

    // In order for your Web app to serve a default page without the user having to fully qualify the URI,
    app.UseDefaultFiles();

    // Enable service of static files in wwwroot folder
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = (context) => 
        {
            // Disable caching for all static files
            context.Context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = Configuration["StaticFiles:Headers:Cache-Control"];
            context.Context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = Configuration["StaticFiles:Headers:Pragma"];
            context.Context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = Configuration["StaticFiles:Headers:Expires"];
        }
    });

    // Enable the use of asp.net mvc framework
    app.UseMvc();     

    // Initialize auto mapper
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Item, ItemViewModel>());

    // Seed database
    dbSeeder.SeedIt();               
}
```

The exception goes away if I remove the dbSeeder from the Startup class. I would really appreciate if someone could point out to me what is happening here.

Comment: are you using `dotnet run` from within the same directory as the project or are you using it from a different directory? (e.g. `dotnet run -p path/to.csproj`)

Comment: yes I am using dotnet run from within the same directory as the project sources are. It works fine if I remove the DbSeeder from code.

Comment: because it looks like the connection string cannot be read from the configuration since the call to `UseNpgsql()` throws (which is transitively executed while `DbSeeder` is resolved because it probably depends on a context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment of Martin Ullrich pointed me in the right direction:

> it looks like the connection string cannot be read from the configuration since the call to UseNpgsql() throws

The connection string could indeed not be read from the configuration. In my project I have two different appsettings files: `appsettings.development.json` and `appsettings.json`. Only the former contains the connection string. When I run the application in Visual Studio Code it starts in debug environment and is therefore able to read the connection string.

Running the application from the terminal with `dotnet run` however seems to run the application in production environment. After changing the environment used in the terminal to development (`export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`) everything works fine.